# I can't get "file" property on GtkImage using g_object_get, nor g_object_get_property

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I've a GtkImage inside a GtkEventBox, defined on glade

```
 <object class="GtkEventBox" id="eb_paciente">
    <signal name="button-press-event" handler="print_filepath" object="bt_icn_paciente" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkImage" id="bt_icn_paciente">
       <property name="pixbuf">img/patient_icons/icon_patient.png</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
```

What I'm trying to do is to change the image path when the EventBox is clicked.

I did this before creating the eventbox hardcoded and was working like a charm. But now I can't get the "file" property. I've tried both ways, using `g_object_get` and `g_object_get_property`, but I allways get a NULL object as response, never the filename.

Here is my code

```
gboolean print_filepath(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent  *event, gpointer *data){
  GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;

  g_value_init (&value, G_TYPE_STRING);
  g_object_get_property(G_OBJECT(gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_EVENT_BOX(widget))), "file", &value);
  g_print("\n print_filepath = %s\n",  g_value_get_string(&value));

  gchar *filepath;
  g_object_get(G_OBJECT(data), "file", &filepath, NULL);
  g_print("\n print_filepath = %s\n", filepath);
  g_free(filepath);

  return FALSE;
}
```

I've done a deep search on internet and found nothing about it. I'm trying to figure out another solution to achieve what I want to but I have no idea what to do. I would appreciate any help or suggetions.
What can I do to change the image file when click on a event box?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point is that you or rather `GtkBuilder` don't initialize the `file` property of your `GtkImage` object. So you get the expected default value of `file` namely `NULL`.

Instead `glade` seems to set the `pixbuf` property to the file path by default. That is perfectly valid and documented in the `GtkBuilder UI Definitions` section of the reference:

> Pixbufs can be specified as a filename of an image file to load

I changed the line

```
<property name="pixbuf">img/patient_icons/icon_patient.png</property>
```

of your ui definitions file to

```
<property name="file">img/patient_icons/icon_patient.png</property>
```

and it works as initially expected on my system.

Comment: Great man! I've tried this before, but I was using both definintions, `pixbuf` and `file`, since pixbuf was the last it was overwriting file property. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

from answer of user1146332
changing the line

```
<property name="pixbuf">img/patient_icons/icon_patient.png</property>
```

to

```
<property name="file">img/patient_icons/icon_patient.png</property>
```

will allow you to get the file name. Thanks to you.

In python, you get the filename like this:

```
ImageFileName = widget.get_property('file')
```

If you plan on designing on glade and modifying your *.glade file. You will have to modify it everytime.
Here is some code to "repair" that file. I've done it in Python, if it's of use for anyone.

```
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class ModifyXML:
    def ChangePropertyPixbuf():


    print("start")


#____________________________________________


        tree = ET.parse("test image.glade")

        root = tree.getroot()


        for ChgValue in root.findall(".//*[@class='GtkImage']"):

            ChgValueb = ChgValue.find(".//*[@name='pixbuf']")

            if ChgValueb is not None:

                ValueOfb = ChgValueb.text

                if ChgValueb.text != "" : ChgValue.remove(ChgValueb)

                ChgValueb = ET.SubElement(ChgValue,'property')

                ChgValueb.set("name", "file")

                ChgValueb.text = ValueOfb

        tree.write("test image.glade")

#_________________________________________

print("done")


ModifyXML.ChangePropertyPixbuf()
```